# Ordered bike parts, paid with Paypal, received face masks. How do I get my money back from this scam?

Tags: scams, paypal, dispute, chargeback

My wife fell victim to a scam that she will not let go of. She was looking for a bicycle online and came across what appeared to be a legit web site. My wife assumed that it was safe to use Paypal because recipients would not get her credit card number and in the past, PayPal has refunded charges when she was scammed.

The listed price was suspiciously low and I assumed that it was a Prime Day deal and I didn't question it. I later found out that the  purchase wasn't from Amazon or any other notable bike seller that I have heard of.

After two weeks we received a package from China that contained a pack of face masks in Chinese writing. The sender's address matched the name of the "bike shop".

I have heard about other mask scams where people use sock puppets (an online identity used for purposes of deception) for such scams.  I immediately checked out the site saw immediately that it was a clumsily assembled WordPress site. The TLS cert was legit and the only pay option was Paypal which was a red flag.

We submitted a dispute.  A few days later we received an automated email stating that they have contacted the seller and that we have to work with them for a refund (yes, go work with the fox to get your hens back... Great idea Paypal!). For weeks we heard nothing  after emailing them almost daily.  We finally got an email entirely in Chinese which I think says that we need to ship the masks to another address in China, but we honestly don't know how to address it. I guess we could print out what I think is the address, cut and paste it to the envelope, and take it to the post office and ask them for help?

Further attempts reaching out to Paypal have led to nothing. What is the best course of action is for us at this point?

Comment: "...they have refunded her from scammers in the past.". Maybe you and your wife should address this, repeatedly falling for scams and expecting PayPal to keep you safe seems like a bad practice.

Comment: @Kat Yeah we had a talk. lol!

Comment: From a seller's perspective, I should say Paypal is even more harsh on that side. Don't fool yourself they are "working together", actually Paypal has a strict procedure that penalises a seller even if they refund you a payment in the end.

I know this doesn't help you much, that's why only leaving a comment, not an answer. Probably, this time their procedure didn't work – I'd guess the scammer creates many Paypal accounts and uses them one-off.

They definitely need to do something about it. Good luck to you and you wife!

Comment: Oh, and also – in case of a dispute they can't send any message to you directly via Paypal, they have to answer to the dispute via the Paypal dashboard TO Paypal, not to you. If they have emailed you directly, you may as well ignore it and continue the Paypal procedure.

Comment: @caffeinum Yup can confirm. Paypal is absolutely brutal and merciless to sellers. They'll put a person out of business and throw them right onto the street if the paypal gods suspect that the buyer even so much as whispered the word "refund" in front of their computer.

Comment: What I don't understand about this scam is why bother sending a box of masks?

Comment: because if the seller can't produce a mail tracking number when PayPal requests, PayPal will automatically rule in the buyer's favor.   Literally - that is an aspect of the dispute process they can automate via scripts, no human need be involved.

Comment: @jwezorek becuase its significantly easier to pull of if there has been a package sent, regardless of package contents, because many online sales platforms try to protect buyers by requesting racking numbers etc. and they can then just pull out the tracking number or the masks, at much lower cost then sending the actual product. Additionally, It doesn't have to be masks, previously seeds were used, it just has to be something cheap to make and cheap to ship (therefore small and light).

Comment: I got hit with basically the exact same scam. Paypal eventually rejected my refund- the seller offered to give me a 30% refund which I found unacceptable (since, you know, I still didn't have a pool ladder)...but Paypal decided that since the seller had offered to settle  that I should have been reasonable.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

PayPal has a couple of articles that discuss the dispute process. One is [addressed to the buyer](https://www.paypal.com/fk/webapps/mpp/security/buyer-protection-resolution), and the other is [addressed to the seller](https://www.paypal.com/us/brc/article/customer-disputes-claims-chargebacks-bank-reversals). The seller’s article is perhaps more informative: it discusses the process and the differences between a *dispute*, *claim*, *chargeback*, and *bank reversal*.

From your question, it seems that you issued a *dispute*. After you issue a *dispute*, you are supposed to try to work it out with the seller. If you can’t come to a quick agreement, you can elevate it to a *claim* within 20 days of filing the *dispute*, and PayPal will look into it.

If 20 days has already passed without you escalating, your *dispute* has probably been closed by PayPal. If it has, you may need to file another *dispute*, then quickly escalate it to a *claim*.

If you feel that PayPal is not being responsive, and if you funded your PayPal purchase with a credit card, then another option is to initiate a *chargeback* with your credit card company.  But, if I were you, I would give PayPal another chance to do this right first, making sure I filed the *claim* correctly (not merely a *dispute*).

If you funded your PayPal purchase with a checking account, then unfortunately, a *chargeback* is not an option, and neither is a *bank reversal*.  Banks only reverse charges if it was an unauthorized transaction, and this charge was indeed authorized by your wife.

PayPal’s ultimate deadline seems to be 180 days from the payment date, so get this resolved before then.

Also, I would not bother trying to send back the masks given the information you have received.  You really don't know what the Chinese e-mail you received is actually saying, and I think it would be a mistake to attempt to send the masks back to China with that information, especially since it is most likely all a scam anyway.  In my opinion, if you send a business a customer service request in English (or any language), and don't receive a reply in the same language, it is really the same as no response at all.

Comment: Thank you, I asked her to follow the next step after reading about this. She actually just got a call back that said they are refunding her the amount as the company was already under investigation. I am glad it is resolved but if they already knew this company was under investigation then why would thier dispute process not check for this automatically?

Comment: "PayPal’s ultimate deadline seems to be 180 days from the payment date, so get this resolved before then." The credit card deadline is 60 days from the statement date that the charge appears on, so if it's not resolved by then, a chargeback should be made. "if you send a business a customer service request in English (or any language), and don't receive a reply in the same language, it is really the same as no response at all." The primary issue isn't what language the request is made in, but what language the business is done in.

Comment: @maple_shaft I am assuming that the shell accounts that these companies set up with Pay Pal do not last long.  An initial scam may not have had any dots to connect to, but they may be there now.  This does seem to be the kind of scam that Paypal is having a very hard time dealing with.  (I am someone who fell victim to this scam.  Paypal handled my claim quite quickly, but for all I know, I was on the tail end of the scammer's hit list, so maybe it was easier then)

Comment: "(...) and neither is a bank reversal. Banks only reverse charges if it was an unauthorized transaction, and this charge was indeed authorized by your wife." 
For which country is this? Because for example here in The Netherlands it's perfectly possible to reverse an automatic withdrawal (*incasso storneren*). 
And you'd still owe PayPal the money of course (also true for a CC chargeback), you might want to mention that in the answer, because it just shifts your problem when PayPal will send it to collections.

Answer (score 23):

+1 to @Ben Miller for explaining how to file a dispute with PayPal.

Last year I ordered a FlashFish Power station.  The price was suspiciously low but the web site appeared legitimate.  They provided me with a USPS tracking number and every few days I received an E-mail update as to which city the package had passed through.  Eventually I received a confirmation of delivery (bogus) that the package had been delivered to my mail box.  Not only did I not receive the package but it was impossible for something the size of a car battery to fit in it.

I called my local post office and they verified that they had delivered the battery to an address in an adjacent town.

Next, I contacted my credit card and submit a dispute.  Although it took two weeks, they resolved this issue and refunded the charge.

The one piece of mind that I had was that I used a one time virtual credit card number (VCCN) for the amount of the purchase which meant that the recipient could not charge anything else since the VCCN ceased to exist after being used once.

While my answer doesn't help you resolve your current  problem, a VCCN is a safe way to place online orders and should you run into similar difficulty again, the ability to dispute a charge is easier with a credit card and they are more effective at resolving such issues promptly.

Comment: How did you get a virtual credit card number?

Comment: I'll add that you'll still want to avoid scams though. It's not painless to dispute a charge via credit card. You have to document a good-faith attempt to resolve the issue with the vendor before your credit card company will do the chargeback. And of course scammers aren't acting in good faith, so it's still a painful process. I love the VCCN idea though; at least you know a criminal doesn't now have your credit card number.

Comment: @xxbbcc - A virtual credit card number is a service offered by a traditional credit card.  There's no fee for my card.  You log into the web site, click the "request VCCN", indicate a dollar amount and if I recall correctly, set  a time limit.  The specific details may vary among cards that offer VCCNs.

Comment: @BobBaerker Can you be more specific - are you talking about US and if yes, which credit card and issuer? I'm asking because Bank of America used to have this service (I used it all the time) but it was discontinued a few years back. I'd want to use this if available but I haven't found this service since then.

Comment: @xxbbcc - I doubt that it's card specific but it's the Citibank 2% rebate Mastercard.  I just logged in and with a few clicks I generated a VCCN with the option to select a dollar limit as well as an expiration of 0 to 2 months. For use with phone or online purchases.

Comment: How did you know the package was too small to fit a battery if you never received the package?

Comment: Do you know the size of your mailbox?  Would something "the size of a car battery" fit in it or not?